# libjpeg issue - jpeglibmangler.h has unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, libjpeg

I'm trying to use boost::gil (boost v. 57), which seems to require libjpeg library. libjpeg.lib is added to Additional external libraries.

im using just one string of code:

```
 boost::gil::jpeg_read_image( "C:/pic.jpg" /*prewData.fileName*/, runtime_image);
```

and this cause some unresolved external symbol errors (they are all leads into jpeglibmangler.h)

> Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "chromium_ijg_jpeg_std_error" referenced in function "protected: void __cdecl boost::gil::detail::jpeg_reader::init(void)" (?init@jpeg_reader@detail@gil@boost@@IEAAXXZ)

Going into jpeglibmangler.h and Ctrl + right clicking on chromium_ijg_jpeg_std_error leads to nowhere. So what is chromium_ijg_jpeg_std_error and what should i include or add into externals to add libjpeg properly?

Comment: im using Win10. I thought i have all required libs, any suggestions on how to make sure this is the case?

Comment: Oh I see `C:/...`. You might want to try using back slash with an escape character: `"C:\\pic.jpg"`.

Comment: @OrhanG.Hafif `C:/` is fine under visual studio / windows. I use that all the time.

Comment: Since you don't use this method all the time: `boost::gil::jpeg_read_image` imo it worth trying.

Comment: That in no way will fix a linker error.

Comment: Since the output is in Russian, I couldn't read. I suggest using English development environment. This way you can get more information about your errors by just searching. Please also provide more info.

Comment: Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "chromium_ijg_jpeg_std_error" referenced in function "protected: void __cdecl boost::gil::detail::jpeg_reader::init(void)" (?init@jpeg_reader@detail@gil@boost@@IEAAXXZ)

Comment: `chromium_ijg_jpeg_std_error` is not defined at that line. `jpeg_std_error` is defined at that line. The problem is `libjpeg.lib` does not provide `chromium_ijg_jpeg_std_error`

Comment: I am not sure why `chromium` is involved at all. I think that is the reason for the linker error. You probably need to update your include paths to get the `chromium` headers out of the system include paths.

Comment: @drescherjm, yes, right. I'm deleting my comments since I wasn't making sense from the beginning. I should probably go to sleep; I hardly recognized now that there's a third person. I think he put a folder in the project or smth. instead of including correct libs. tester [take a look at this example and its libs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/gil/example/resize.cpp)

Comment: No problem, I have had days like this... Sorry to have to correct you so many times.. I mean you no offense.

Comment: No I'm sorry about spreading wrong comments.